# Apply displayNone to certain class depending on selected field in other classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide an element when a certain option value is selected from a fieldset drop down. I am unsure how to use jQuery to read the text contained in the option value (either the actual text or the value is fine):

```
<div class="filter_options">
            <input id="search_query" type="hidden" value="Texts" />
            <fieldset class="filterType">

                <label>Filter By Type</label><select id="search_filter_type">

<option value="">All</option>
<option value="Cat">Cat</option>
<option value="Dog">Dog</option></select></fieldset>

        </div>
```

and then hide the certain div classes "pg_list" which do not contain the selected value.

```
            <div class="pg_list">
             <p>This text contains a Dog</p>
            </div>

            <div class="pg_list">
             <p>This text contains a Cat</p>
            </div>

            <div class="pg_list">
             <p>This text contains a Rabbit</p>
            </div>
```

So If I choose option value - Cat, then it would hide the div containing Dog or Rabbit, and leave Cat.

Lastly, I have the following .css ready to go:

```
.displayNone{
display: none;
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Here is my jQuery for a input text field which works, but I can't work out how to use the same basis to work for a selected drop down:

```
$('input').on('keypress keyup', function(){
var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
if (value != '') {

  $('.pg_list').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {
      $(this).removeClass('displayNone');  
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('displayNone');
    }
  });
} else {
  $('.pg_list').removeClass('displayNone');
}
```

});

Thank you for reading.

Comment: $('select').on('change', function(){}

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for this, it is working, however if I make the option value "Cat Pictures" it will not work. It's like when there's a space it does not work properly, without spaces it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to select the correct component, which is the dropdown box: `$('#search_filter_type')`. Second, you want this to occur when the value of the dropdown box is changed: `$('#search_filter_type').on('change', ...`

```js
$('#search_filter_type').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).find('option:selected').text().toLowerCase();
  if (value != "all") {

    $('.pg_list').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {
        $(this).removeClass('displayNone');
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('displayNone');
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('.pg_list').removeClass('displayNone');
  }
});
```

```css
.displayNone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter_options">
  <input id="search_query" type="hidden" value="Texts" />
  <fieldset class="filterType">

    <label>Filter By Type</label>
    <select id="search_filter_type">

      <option value="">All</option>
      <option value="Cats">Cat Pictures</option>
      <option value="Dogs">Dog Pictures</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>

</div>
<div class="pg_list">
  <p>This text contains a Dog Pictures</p>
</div>

<div class="pg_list">
  <p>This text contains a Cat Pictures</p>
</div>

<div class="pg_list">
  <p>This text contains a Rabbit</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Dware What exactly did not work? Does the snippet I provided work the way you want it to?

Comment: Hi sorayadragon, sorry, to clarify, please see my post above to simon. Basically, if the text contains a space, it does not seem to work, but without any spaces it works. It's odd, not sure why this would happen?

Comment: @Dware So, if you change the value **attribute** of the `<option>`, it won't work because your sample text in the `pg_list` div doesn't include "Cat Pictures". This solution does still work if you change the actual text of the option.

Comment: OK it seems you are right, the website is generating a dash for a space for the option value, but the text obviously doesn't have the dash. Damn, was so close. Is there anything that can be done to ignore dashes perhaps? Alternatively, can I make it read the option text instead of the value?

Comment: @Dware I updated my solution to look at the text in the option instead of at the value.

Comment: Very clever! It works, however, now when selecting the top option "All", it will not display anything and hides all of the elements. Your original solution did not have this issue

Comment: @Dware Good point. Instead of checking that `value != ""`, you'll have to check if `value != "all"`. I updated my solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, to read the value of a `<select>`, it's the same as `<input>`:

```
$('#my-select').val(); // where this is your select
```

You can put it in a `change` event, which is what fires when it is changed:

```
$('#my-select').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    // rest of your code
});
```

If you want the text of the selected option, you can use this instead:

```
$('#my-select').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    // rest of your code
});
```

A slight improvement to your design though would be to add a class to each of your `<div>` elements which match the value of your options. Then, instead of having to loop through, you can use `not()` to set it on everything except the one you want to leave visible.

```js
$('select').on('change', function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#divs').children() // all children of the proper parent
    .removeClass('displayNone') // remove 'displayNone' from them all
    .not('.' + value) // remove the one we aren't hiding
    .addClass('displayNone'); // add 'displayNone' to all remaining
});
```

```css
.displayNone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="rabbit">Rabbit</option>
</select>
<div id="divs">
  <div class="cat">Cat</div>
  <div class="dog">Dog</div>
  <div class="rabbit">Rabbit</div>
</div>
```

By doing it this way, you aren't locking yourself in to them always having matching text, giving you better flexibility. You also don't have to loop through and do a text comparison.

Comment: Thank you, will look into making this better